# Replace the cell with the most frequent word in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Source1': ['Corona,Corona,Corona','Sars,Sars','Corona,Sars',
                          'Sars,Corona','Sars'], 
'Area': ['A,A,A,B','A','A,B,B,C','C,C,B,C','A,B,C']})

df

                Source1     Area
0  Corona,Corona,Corona  A,A,A,B
1             Sars,Sars        A
2           Corona,Sars  A,B,B,C
3           Sars,Corona  C,C,B,C
4                  Sars    A,B,C
```

I want to check each cell in each column (the real data has many columns) and find the frequency of each unique word (we can distinguish the unique words by ','), and replace the whole entry by the most frequent word.

In the case of a tie, it doesn't matter which word to replace. So the desired output would look like this:

```
df
    Source Area
0  Corona    A
1    Sars    A
2  Corona    B
3    Sars    C
4    Sars    A
```

In this case, I randomly chose to pick the first word when there is a tie, but it really doesn't matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `DataFrame`s by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and `expand=True` and is used [`DataFrame.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) with selecting first column by position:

```
df['Source1'] = df['Source1'].str.split(',', expand=True).mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
df['Area'] = df['Area'].str.split(',', expand=True).mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
  Source1 Area
0  Corona    A
1    Sars    A
2  Corona    B
3    Sars    C
4    Sars    A
```

Another idea with [`collections.Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
from collections import Counter

f = lambda x: [Counter(y.split(',')).most_common(1)[0][0] for y in x]
df[['Source1', 'Area']] = df[['Source1', 'Area']].apply(f)
#all columns
#df = df.apply(f)
print (df)
  Source1 Area
0  Corona    A
1    Sars    A
2  Corona    B
3    Sars    C
4    Sars    A
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do we use different techniques for the two columns, where it looks like they both do the same thing? Can we use the same code for both columns? (and apply it to all the columns since I have a lot of columns on my real data)?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do `df['Source1'] = df['Source1'].str.split(',', expand=True).mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]` for the `'Source1'` column as well? `df['Source1'] = df['Source1'].str.split(',').str[0]` would only return the first word not the most frequent one.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my offering that can be executed in a single line for each series and requires no extra `imports`.

```py
df['Area'] = df['Area'].apply(lambda x: max(x.replace(',',''), key=x.count))
```

After replacing all `,` in the characters found in the `Area` series, we replace the field with the element that has the greatest number of occurrences (or first element in the case of equal values) with the `key=x.count` argument.

You could also use use something similar (demonstrated with the `Source1` series), returning the maximum from the list of elements created by splitting the field.

```py
df['Source1'] = df['Source1'].apply(lambda x: max(list(x.split(',')), key=x.count))
```

```py
+---+---------+------+
|   | Source1 | Area |
+---+---------+------+
| 0 | Corona  | A    |
| 1 | Sars    | A    |
| 2 | Corona  | B    |
| 3 | Sars    | C    |
| 4 | Sars    | A    |
+---+---------+------+
```

Two methods shown above to highlight choices; both would work adequately on either or both series.